# Resharper code formatting does not work for html files

Tags: html, visual-studio, formatting, resharper

I would like to have each HTML attribute on a single line:

```
<input 
  id="title" 
  type="text" 
  class="form-control" 
  data-bind="value: title, attr: { placeholder: language.getValue('measureName_placeholder') }" 
/>
```

In order to get this, I activated the settings "Each attribute on separate lines" in ReSharper. However, if I format the file no line breaks are inserted. All the attributes still stay on a single line:

```
<input id="title" type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: title, attr: { placeholder: language.getValue('measureName_placeholder') }" />
```

I use R# 9.2 with Visual Studio Community 2015. To reproduce the issue: open VisualStudio, create a new html file, select all content and format the code. (Command "Format Selection" in the context menu for the selection). The result which I then get is

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I would expect the attributes lang and xmlns to be on seperate lines.

Is this a ReSharper bug or do I miss an additional setting or so that prevents ReSharper from actually inserting the the line breaks?

The code formatting entries seem to be correctly included in the settings file:

```
<s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/HtmlFormatter/ProcessingInstructionAttributesFormat/@EntryValue">OnDifferentLines</s:String>
<s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/HtmlFormatter/TagAttributesFormat/@EntryValue">OnDifferentLines</s:String>
```

[image]

Comment: Works in R# 9.2 as expected. Which R# version do you use?

Comment: I use R# 9.2 with Visual Studio Community 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I did not really use Resharper to format the code but the Visual Studio Actions **Edit.FormatDocument** or **Edit.FormatSelection**.

Using the Resharer **Cleanup** Command or the **Format Selection** Command that is available from the **brush icon** works fine.

[image]

I could not find a Resharper Command / Key Action for directly (re)formatting the document. The solution is to prepare an extra cleanup profile and assign it to the Command **ReSharper_SilentCleanupCode**:

https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5466964;jsessionid=441D909EA354C48AEF75264A4F77B97E

(A custum key shortcut (e.g. Ctrl+Shift+F) can be assigned to that command in the key settings.)

[image]